# How to discern, if a directory is NFS-mounted from Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, stat, fstat

I need to set up an application directory for a "hairy" app. Depending on the case, the directory may be local to each server participating, or shared among several servers via NFS.

So, I need to be able to detect, whether the given path is local or NFS-accessed and skip some of the tasks in the latter case.

What's the best way to detect this in an Ansible role?

I tried using the [stat module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html), but `device_type` seems to be set to 0 in *all* cases, NFS or local (XFS).

On Linux I could invoke `stat -f /path` -- this would output details, including the type (the utility uses the `statfs` syscall). But this is a Linux-only method, and I'd rather avoid such petty OS-dependencies (same goes for the `mountpoint` utility).

I would write a custom library function, but there is no `os.statfs` in Python...

What's left?

Comment: Recent Ansible versions can execute binary modules as well. Make a tiny statically compiled module in C or Go.

Comment: That's even more OS-dependent, though... I'll need an executable for every target OS/release/architecture :( Will Ansible even be smart enough to look in different library/ subdirectories for such executables?

Comment: The solutions that were ruled-out here as too platform-specific actually worked for me! In case anyone would like to try them, I posted my production Ansible code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49615669/1268949

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would make use of Ansible facts. You could filter the *ansible_mounts* array for your mount=*your mount point* and extract the filesystem type field. For an example, please see the answer I got here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49662135/1268949 .

Another example from my production code:

```
- name: Determine shared-dir mount point
command: "/usr/bin/env stat -c '%m' {{ shared_dir_real_path }}"
register: shared_dir_mount_point
changed_when: False

- name: Determine the mount point's filesystem type and mount options
set_fact:
    "shared_dir_mount_{{ item }}": "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', shared_dir_mount_point.stdout) | map(attribute = item) | join(',') }}"
with_items:
    - fstype
    - options
```

Answer (score 1):

If the GNU *stat* utility is available on your target platforms, then you can invoke it in a way that doesn't make use of the *statfs* call to detect the mount-point and then search it in the output of *mount*, e.g. on Linux:

```
$ mount | grep -F `stat -c %m /boot/grub` | cut -d' ' -f5
ext2
```

I verified that this invocation of *stat* only makes use of standard system calls (see CONFORMING TO in the man page of *stat(2)*):

```
$ strace stat -c %m /boot/grub/ |& fgrep stat
execve("/usr/bin/stat", ["stat", "-c", "%m", "/boot/grub/"], [/* 65 vars */]) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=218501, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=130224, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=456632, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14608, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=138696, ...}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffe62882ff0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffe62882ff0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5152256, ...}) = 0
lstat("/boot/grub/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
lstat("/boot", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3072, ...}) = 0
lstat("/boot/grub", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/boot/grub", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
stat("..", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3072, ...}) = 0
stat("..", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/boot", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3072, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's still Linux-only. On BSD, for example, stat is rather different. And output of mount is different too :(

Comment: Are GNU coreutils available for BSD? Seems like many GNU utilities have ports to OS/X which is BSD-derived via *brew* etc. If worse comes to worst you can always have multiple version of the step that determines this, and run the right one according to appropriate *when* conditions.

Comment: On FreeBSD they are available, but the `stat` executable is installed as `gnustat`. It could work. Instead of parsing its output -- and relying on mount's output format -- one could just `stat -f --format=%T /path/of/interest`. I guess, that's how I'd do it... Please, update your answer so I can "accept" it.

Comment: %T means "minor device type in hex", so just be sure you're relying on a documented interface here...

Comment: No, when stat-ing filesystems (with the `-f` flag), `%T` means "file system type in human readable form".